# Programmatically modify url startpage?

Tags: url, liferay

I'd like to modify the page where the user ends up if he isn't recognized.
I'm using a token login system so they're redirected to /c/portal/login by a different system.
I'm having some issues with response.sendRedirect (posted another question for that), so I was hoping I could programmatically modify the url startpage, but so far I haven't found something that has the same function as last_path but then for the startpage in webkeys.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hook with a custom "Login Post Action". You'll find some [outdated information here](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+redirect+after+login) (it speaks about the ext-environment, but you should do it in a hook). Liferay IDE or Liferay Developer Studio will help with the generation of such a hook. The code you find in the Wiki should be ok. Otherwise google for more samples (Login Post Action is the keyword: This is code that will be executed just after a successful login)

Comment: While this is certainly the correct way to modify the LAST_PATH (the landing page after a succesfull login), what I'm trying to do is to modify the start page. which is where you're sent in case the login fails.